# Targets must be 1-dimensional Top_k_categorical_accuracy in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I've just finished training an Inception V3 CNN and I'm trying to measure accuracy on the training dataset, specifically, top-k accuracy. I invoke the function called `top_k_categorical_accuracy` from `tensorflow.keras.metrics` ordering my parameters properly `(y_true, y_pred, k)` but I receive an error saying my targets `(y_true)` should be 1-dimensional. However, when I print the shape of `y_true` (which are the targets, if I understand correctly) I get `(9000,)`, which, to me, seems 1-dimensional.

Both arrays have a `dtype = "float32"` since I read in a thread that this caused problem, but this does not solve my problem.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.applications import InceptionV3
from keras.applications.inception_v3 import preprocess_input

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess_input)

test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    "data/test",
    target_size=(299, 299),
    batch_size=16,
    class_mode="categorical",
    shuffle=True,
    seed=42,
)

STEP_SIZE_TEST = test_generator.n // test_generator.batch_size


model = keras.models.load_model("inceptionv3.hdf5")

results = model.evaluate_generator(test_generator, STEP_SIZE_TEST, workers=8)

y_pred = model.predict_generator(test_generator)
print(y_pred.shape) # Prints (9000, 6)
y_true = test_generator.classes
y_true = y_true.astype("float32") 
print(y_true.shape) #Prints (9000,)

top_k = tf.keras.metrics.top_k_categorical_accuracy(y_true, y_pred, k=2)
```

The exact error I get is this : `tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: targets must be 1-dimensional [Op:InTopKV2]`

If I resize y_pred to a 1D array, I get the following error : `tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: predictions must be 2-dimensional [Op:InTopKV2]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Yoskutik suggested in the comments of his answer : As written in documentation, y_true may be a matrix. Try to convert it to a categorical array:

`y_true = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_true)`

This is what worked in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this one?

```py
y_pred = np.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)
```

As I understand you have something like `Dense(6, activation='softmax')` at last layer. That's why `y_pred` is matrix. The script above can help.

Comment: It seems like you're trying to solve a problem with the predictions array, which is supposed to be 2-dimensional. Y_pred is supposed to be a matrix, targets (y_true) are supposed to be 1-dimensional. I'll edit my question to reflect that. Doing this modification results in this error : ```tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: predictions must be 2-dimensional [Op:InTopKV2]```

Comment: Maybe they are supposed to be this dimentions. But keras can't compare 1D and 2D arrays. You must convert them to the same dimension

Comment: As written in documentation, `y_true` may be a matrix. Try to convert it to a categorical array: `y_true = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_true)`

Comment: This worked, I'll post an answer referring this comment.

Comment: Will do as soon as the 2 day wait time is over.